How to reference ordinal columns in an expression when adding additional columns in a Copy Activity in Azure Data Factory
I am simply trying to trim spaces from a column from a text file with no header but am not able to refer to the ordinal columns when adding an additional column in a Copy Activity in ADF.
This is when trying to use the Custom option but ordinals do not show up.
enter image description here
I was expecting the ordinal columns to show up in the drop down to use in an expression. Just like when a file has a header row and you see the columns in the drop down.

In general, if there are no headers in a csv file the copy activity additional column will show the column names like below.

The possible reason that you are not getting these might be that there is no file existing or there is no data in the file. As you are using the dynamic copy activity inside for-each loop, you need to ensure the files are present or not in the given data location.

Coming to your requirement, it might not be possible using copy activity as you cannot edit or get the column values. If you try to trim() by specifying column name in the dynamic expression of the new additional column, you can see it's giving the error saying it as Unrecognized expression.

You need to use ADF Dataflow for this kind of operations.
Create dataflow source with your csv file and pass your filename to dataflow activity via dataset parameters inside your loop.
After source, add a derived column transformation and create new column. Here, you can handle the columns and rows data using dataflow expressions. Use the below expression to trim the existing column.
Here, if you are handling with dynamic datasets, the below expression will check for the column name _col0_ and it will give the values if it exists. If not, it will give null rows.
trim(toString(byName('_col0_')))


Add your sink dataset after it and the dataflow will be executed from the pipeline.
Result:


Thanks for this suggestion Rakesh. unfortunately i need to stick with the Copy activity rather than Data Flow at this point. I think this is a significant weakness in the Copy activity as we need to be able to truly Customize an ordinal column with Dynamic content such as a simple trim() when mapping to the sink.

As I mentioned, Copy activity cannot deal with column and row transformations. You can copy your source data to Blob or gen 2 first to use data flow on this. If you need, you can raise a feature request on this.
